# Is there any automated system available that validate the accuracy of the data generated by GenAI?

Tags: chatgpt, llm, hallucination, accuracy

For example, I prompt GenAI to write an essay on "world war I". GenAI generated a 200 words "world war I overview" essay. How a user or student will insure and trust the data generated by ChatGPT or any LLM, is 100 percent accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How a user or student will insure and trust the data generated by ChatGPT or any LLM, is 100 percent accurate?

That can't be done automatically. There are many papers and systems on [automated fact checking](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.11896.pdf) and [hallucination reduction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.08263.pdf), but none of them will guarantee that the generated text is 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step approach that I follow (again this may not work 100%)

1. Every prompt that I enter for creating a factually correct information add the following statement in prompt - `Ensure to keep data factually correct and show me references for all facts mentioned`
2. Go to Google Bard -
   Ask it to run a reference check and give you link of references.
3. Ask Google Bard to check for all factual inaccuracy in data - this is like a double check to ensure everything is good to go.

Again it works 95% times for me, feel free to use it.

Comment: *Again it works 95% times for me* - How can you tell when it does not work?

Comment: I will check the reference links for each fact , takes a bit more time but worth it